# Rules of matrix multiplication

Tags: linear-algebra

With rules of matrix multiplication, is there any way I can figure out what the multiplicand is –in this case, a matrix– with knowing the multiplier and the product?

[Attached is my work so far](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QW0t7.png)

Everything relates to a problem in finding the standard matrix across a plane.

Comment: Of course not.  That's like asking "I have an equation $a x = y$.  Can you tell me anything about $y$ if I know nothing about $a$ or $x$?"

Comment: For the very last equation? Yes, you can find all matrices that solve that equation. Note that if you name take  $9$ entries of the matrix as unknowns, then the equation gives a linear system of 3 equations and $9$ unknowns. You can then compute a parametrization, of its set of solutions.

Comment: Hi, thank you so much!! For the last equitation, how would I be able to compute a parametrization?

Comment: I am having trouble following the writing, are you trying to find out what is $[F]$?

Comment: Yes, I am trying to find $[F]$